# I used sync package but I get Deadlock error in Golang ;(

Tags: go, deadlock, goroutine

I was so excited that I wrote a Go code to learn goroutine.

And then

In the process of learning goroutine, I applied the sync package and channel to generate the following code.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)


var waitGroup sync.WaitGroup

func writeToChannel(c chan int, x int) {

    fmt.Println(x)
    c <- x // c라는 채널에 x값을 쓴다.
    fmt.Println(x)
    close(c) // 통신 종료

    waitGroup.Done()
}

func main() {

    c := make(chan int)

    waitGroup.Add(1)
    go writeToChannel(c, 10)
    waitGroup.Wait()

}
```

After that, I compiled it, but the following error occurred.

```
junbeomhan@acd:~/Documents/workspace/go/src/go-routine$ go run writeCh.go 
10
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [semacquire]:
sync.runtime_Semacquire(0xc000014270?)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/sema.go:62 +0x27
sync.(*WaitGroup).Wait(0x0?)
        /usr/local/go/src/sync/waitgroup.go:116 +0x4b
main.main()
        /home/junbeomhan/Documents/workspace/go/src/go-routine/writeCh.go:22 +0x85

goroutine 6 [chan send]:
main.writeToChannel(0x0?, 0xa)
        /home/junbeomhan/Documents/workspace/go/src/go-routine/writeCh.go:12 +0x75
created by main.main
        /home/junbeomhan/Documents/workspace/go/src/go-routine/writeCh.go:21 +0x79
exit status 2
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: There's no goroutine receiving from the channel `c` so `c <- x` will block forever and therefore `waitGroup.Done` will never execute and therefore `waitGroup.Wait()` will wait forever.

Comment: Your can increase the channel capacity: `make(chan int, 1)`.

Answer (score 3):

`c := make(chan int)` You declared an unbuffered channel, so if there are no consumers consuming this channel, the producer will be blocked. So `go writeToChannel(c, 10)` goroutine is blocked at `c <- x // c라는 채널에 x값을 쓴다.`, can not execute `waitGroup.Done()`. And the main goroutine is blocked by waitGroup, so deadlock occured.

To make this code work, you can just simply consume this unbuffered channel from main goroutine.

```golang
func main() {

    c := make(chan int)

    waitGroup.Add(1)
    go writeToChannel(c, 10)
    num := <-c // new code here
    fmt.Printf("num received %d", num)
    waitGroup.Wait()

}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/1FzQu0-MxJG

Comment: BTW, you can try chatGPT, it can solve this kind of question quickly

Answer (score 0):

**Remember this**: For an unbuffered channel, when you are reading/writing to a channel in a `goroutine` then you need another `goroutine` to write/read from the same channel.

If the above is not happening, you'll have a deadlock.

In your case you are writing to the channel in the `goroutine` but *where are you reading it*? **Nowhere**.

To fix this, you just need to read from the channel right after you kick off the `goroutine`. I.e.

```
func main() {

    c := make(chan int)

    waitGroup.Add(1)
    go writeToChannel(c, 10)
    <- c // read from the channel to avoid deadlock
    waitGroup.Wait()

}
```